# fatal: repository 'https://github.com/directus/zend-db.git/' not found

Tags: php, composer-php, directus

I recently reformatted by computer and currently setting up my web projects. I'm having issues with my projects that are using **Directus** version **7.x** and **8.x**.

Whenever I run `composer install`, I was asked to fill my github username and password twice before an error is display. Note: credential used are correct but still prompted twice.

Here is the error after entering the credentials:

```
In Git.php line 393:
                                                                                                                                                                 
  Failed to execute git clone --mirror 'https://***:***@github.com/directus/zend-db.git' '/home/local/.cache/composer/vcs/https---github.com-directus-zend-db/'  
                                                                                                                                                                 
  Cloning into bare repository '/home/local/.cache/composer/vcs/https---github.com-directus-zend-db'...                                                          
  remote: Repository not found.                                                                                                                                  
  fatal: repository 'https://github.com/directus/zend-db.git/' not found                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                 

install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>...]
```

I was thinking if the issue is caused by composer but when I tried to replicate the issue on my Laravel projects, but it didn't.

Any idea on how to fix this issue? Unfortunately, upgrading to **Directus 9** is not an option.

Comment: According to [this article](https://directus.io/articles/introducing-directus-9/) on their website, Directus has cleaned up their Github repositories. Apparently, they haven't updated all their Composer packages yet. That same article links to a Discord server, this sounds like something you should ask about there.

Comment: Have you checked whether the package you want to install even exists?

Comment: @rickdenhaan, I'll check on Discord and Slack. Thanks.

Comment: @NicoHaase, it was working on my previous setup so I'm pretty sure it existed before.

Comment: The legacy versions are still available on GitHub, but they have been moved to different repositories.